# Python error al guardar .txt porque?

Tags: python

Intento guardar texto de 1 linea en un .txt pero el ultimo apostrofe (') de la linea 19 se guarda en la siguiente linea (linea 2), por que ?.

Adjunto el codigo y una imagen de lo que me arroja la consola al ejecutar el codigo, asi tal cual se guarda en el .txt

```
from io import open
import time
import requests

archivo_texto = open('direcciones_convertir.txt', 'r')
dir_num = len(archivo_texto.readlines())
#print ('Direcciones a verificar: ',dir_num)
archivo_texto.close()


for i in range(0,1):    
    archivo_texto1 = open('direcciones_convertir.txt', 'r') 
    leer_direccion = archivo_texto1.readlines()
    archivo_texto1.close()

    direccion = leer_direccion[i]

    archivo_texto2=open('direcciones_convertidas.txt','a')
    archivo_texto2.write('dir' + str(i) + "='" +  leer_direccion[i] + "'")
    #archivo_texto2.write("'")
    print ('dir' + str(i) + "='" +  leer_direccion[i] + "'")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `.readlines()` lee la línea completa, incluido el `\n` de final de línea. Supongo que es ése el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el error consiste en que el archivo .txt tenga una linea al final que solo contenga `'`. Algo así como:

> Esto es un ejemplo
>   del contenido del archivo txt
>   '

**Bonus:** Esto no tiene que ver con tu error, pero dos consejos:
1: Usa f-strings, es más facil de leer el código si no tienes que usar `+`. Ejemplo:

```
print ('dir' + str(i) + "='" +  leer_direccion[i] + "'")  # Sin f-strings
print (f"dir{i}='{leer_direccion[i]}'")  # Con f-strings
```

2: Utiliza `with open()` (explicacion [aqui](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)) ya que al no cerrar el archivo puede que crees problemas de caché en un futuro. Además, no es necesario importar io. Convertirías esto:

```
archivo_texto = open('direcciones_convertir.txt', 'r')
dir_num = len(archivo_texto.readlines())
archivo_texto.close()
```

en esto:

```
with open('direcciones_convertir.txt', 'r') as archivo_texto:
    dir_num = len(archivo_texto.readlines())
```

Pero el código se asegura 100% que el archivo va a ser cerrado antes de continuar. Ya que el with cierra el archivo automaticamente.